# How to write KSerializer for Map having custom objects

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I want to serializable following class using kotlinx-serializer.

[image]

But since it contains Map with custom types - `HttpUrl` & `List<Cookie>`,it gives an error

1. Serializer has not been found for type 'HttpUrl'
2. Serializer has not been found for type 'Cookie

When Looked into **kotlinx serialization** documentation it looks like I will need to create a **custom KSerializer** for the above map type. so I can add it like below.

```
@Serializable(with = CookieSerializer::class)
val cookies: Map<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>> = emptyMap()
```

I am looking into some inputs on how I can create a custom CookieSerializer, I tried using the following approach, just to see if compile time error is resolved.

```
@Serializer(forClass = Map::class)
object CookieSerializer : KSerializer<Map<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor =
        PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("Cookie", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Map<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>>) {

    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Map<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>> {
        return emptyMap()
    }
}
```

But I still receive an error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The errors indicate that `HttpUrl` and `Cookie` are not serializable. If you control the source for these classes, you can make them serializable by applying `@Serializable`, just like you are making `ApplicationConfiguration` serializable here. Maps are by default serializable in `kotlinx.serialization`.

The code you specify here tries to serialize `Map<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>>` (as a whole) using `CookieSerializer`, which seems unnecessary. If you don't control the source of `Cookie`, you can specify a serializer to use as follows: `val cookies: Map<HttpUrl, List<@Serializable(CookieSerializer::class) Cookie>>`
.

For information on how to write custom serializers, please [refer to the full documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers). It's a bit more intricate than what you are trying to do here (which I recommend you not to do, but just fyi) when writing serializers [for generic types](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers-for-a-generic-type), such as maps.